# What speaker wire should I use to extend the length?

Tags: wire, home-theater, speakers

I bought the [Sony HT-IV300](https://www.flipkart.com/sony-ht-iv300-5-1-home-cinema/p/itmef7nsefyrtpvb) home theatre system 3 years back.

[Specifications](https://www.sony.co.in/electronics/sound-bars/ht-iv300/specifications) ( Impedance levels are mentioned)

For the front speakers, just used the default surrounding speaker wires ( impedance of front = surrounding = 3 ohm), so no worries about them.

I would like to install the surrounding(rear) speakers of 3-ohm impedance on the walls. The wires are concealed.  So, I need to buy the wires to extend up to 30 feet for each speaker.

Online references/readings lead to confusion as everyone stands on their own standard.

1. Can you guys help me to buy the right wire with right AWG and with a wire gauge chart for distances vs ohm ?
2. Shall I simply buy [14 gauge wire](https://www.amazon.in/AmazonBasics-16-Gauge-Speaker-Wire-Feet/dp/B006LW0WDQ/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?ie=UTF8&qid=1543205111&sr=8-1-spons&keywords=amazon%20basic%20speaker%20wire&psc=1) without thinking too much technical?
3. As the wires are concealed, should i think of [oxygen free copper wires](https://www.amazon.in/AmazonBasics-14-Gauge-Speaker-Wire-Oxygen/dp/B0758CSSF2/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1543211845&sr=8-6&keywords=amazon%20basic%20speaker%20wire)?

Am i really thinking too much?

Answer (score 3):

I would just install 14 gauge wire, it will be more than adequate at 30 feet.

Look for a reputable brand that's made for audio and rated CL2 for in-wall installation.  Any decent speaker wire will be made with fine strands and sufficient purity for your surround system.

You can spend a lot more on speaker wire, but you won't hear any difference.

Comment: In college, I once ran double twisted pair from my dorm window to the courtyard, 100'+ away, to drive a pair of speakers from my stereo. The twisted pair was no heavier than 20 gauge, and probably thinner. Sounded fine to me; even if I had (have?) a tin ear, that means 14 gauge will satisfy any audiophile for at least hundreds of feet.

Comment: Agreed, copper audio grade, but IF  you are going to upgrade to better speakers in the future you may want to put in 12AWG now so you are prepared. I would go with 12 regardless.

Comment: At 30' I don't think 12awg will sound any better than 14awg.